# Trying to compare a rowvalue to form value while in a query using cfif and performing the query

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I know, the title sounds confusing but I literally couldn't think of another way to word it. Anyway, here's what I mean

```
 <cfquery name="search_all" datasource="ContactData">
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          people.first_name,
          people.last_name,
          state_lkp.state,
          zip_lkp.zip,
          number_lkp.phone_number,
          email_lkp.email,
          country_lkp.country,
          address_lkp.address,
          city_lkp.city,
          count(distinct email_lkp.email_id) as mail_count,
          count(distinct number_lkp.phone_number_id) as number_count,
          people.people_id
   FROM   people 
             Left Join state_lkp On state_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
             Left Join zip_lkp On zip_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
             Left Join number_lkp On number_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
             Left Join email_lkp On email_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
             Left Join country_lkp On country_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
             Left Join city_lkp On city_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
             Left Join address_lkp On address_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
  WHERE 
<cfif LCase(people.last_name) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    people.last_name LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif  LCase(people.first_name) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    people.first_name LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif  LCase(address_lkp.address) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    address_lkp.address LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(coutnry_lkp.country) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    country_lkp.country LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(city_lkp.city) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    city_lkp.city LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(state_lkp.state) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    state_lkp.state LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(zip_lkp.zip) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    zip_lkp.zip LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(email_lkp.email) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
   email_lkp.email LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
<cfelseif LCase(number_lkp.phone_number) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    number_lkp.phone_number LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
</cfif>
GROUP BY people.people_id desc;
</cfquery>
```

See the cfif/ cfelseif statements there? When I try to compare something like `people.last_name` to `form.search_bar` I get an error. Probably because ColdFusion doesn't recognize the variable because technically it hasn't been created in the scope of ColdFusion and is still mysql code waiting to be executed.

Now I know there are other ways of doing this (like making a html select drop down and have the user select what they actually want to search for. However I'm curious to see if what I'm doing here is possible with another solution I haven't thought of.

Pic of the error message:
[image: Error Message]

The error itself

> Element LAST_NAME is undefined in PEOPLE.

If I need to clarify something, please let me know. Thanks for taking the time to look at this question.

---

**EDIT:** Note I originally had my query like this:

```
<cfquery name="search_all" datasource="ContactData">
Select distinct
  people.first_name,
  people.last_name,
  state_lkp.state,
  zip_lkp.zip,
  number_lkp.phone_number,
  email_lkp.email,
  country_lkp.country,
  address_lkp.address,
  city_lkp.city,
count(distinct email_lkp.email_id) as mail_count,
count(distinct number_lkp.phone_number_id) as number_count,
people.people_id
From
  people 
Left Join state_lkp On state_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
Left Join zip_lkp On zip_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
Left Join number_lkp On number_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
Left Join email_lkp On email_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
Left Join country_lkp On country_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
Left Join city_lkp On city_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
Left Join address_lkp On address_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
WHERE 

people.last_name LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR people.first_name LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR address_lkp.address LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR country_lkp.country LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR city_lkp.city LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR state_lkp.state LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR zip_lkp.zip LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR email_lkp.email LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
OR number_lkp.phone_number LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))

group by people.people_id desc;
</cfquery>
```

You would think that would work right? It didn't work in the manner I expected. Say, for example, I have 10 entries in the DB, 8 have a country of 'Merica' and 2 have the country of 'Nippon'. The user enters 'Merica' in the field and expects on 'Merica' results. Instead what the result was all the entries, including 'Nippon' ones.

Here, a screenshot:

[image: Oh Nippon]

The text for search results:

```
First Name Last Name Address    City    Zip     Country State   Mail Count Number Count
Test    Subject 123 Imperfect rd Huge   12546   USA     TX  1           1
Yelp    Pley    616 Symmetry Rd Kinikinik 15051 USA     Co  1           1
Son     Goku    560 Nowhere ave None     None  Nippon   None    1           1
My  Addias  8998 Beat St    Breakin 12478   USA     NY  1           1
Gotta   Yolo    123 Only Once st. Miami 04211   USA     FL  1           1
```

What it comes down to this is. If I do a search for Merica results. I only want exactly a WHOLE WORD match of Merica results, not results that contain merica in some combination not in country. Likewise, if I search for 'test subject', I only expect the person test subject to come up. Not test subject and bob because bob has test somewhere in his records.

EDIT: The best I could do to create a self contained environment for this was to create a git with all the necessary files for backed functionality. My hosting provider does not have coldfusion support and I can't install it there because I lack root access via the terminal. Hell,  I can't even sudo install coldfusion on it. But anyway, here's the link to the git. The sql file is there for you to just import into a db schema to create the same one I'm using for this application.

https://github.com/VinceOmega/Contact-Manager

Thanks to all those who attempted to help.

Comment: try this: <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(form.search_bar)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500"> for all your statements instead of how you have it... a little cleaner to read.

Comment: also, try posting the error that you are getting to your message.

Comment: A picture of the error message has been posted.

Comment: RE: *Original query ... Instead what the result was all the entries, including 'Nippon' ones.* I do not understand your expectations here ;-) IF the joins are correct, then those records are included because on **one or more** of the filtered columns contains the search value `Merica`. ie Exactly what your query is telling the database to do .. So if you want a different result, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: What it comes down to this is. If I do a search for Merica results. I only want exactly a WHOLE WORD match of Merica results, not results that contain merica in some combination not in country. Likewise, if I search for 'test subject', I only expect the person test subject to come up. Not test subject and bob because bob has test somewhere in his records. I don't think I can clarify it any further. I'm aware the % matches values like a greedy operator and I'm trying to find a way around that without having the user make a choice.

Comment: Then you should not be using `LIKE`. You should use equals ie `=` instead. The former is for partial matches, the latter is for exact matches.

Comment: Doesn't work, the = sign just results in no results at all.

Comment: Yeah, even when converting everything to lowercase and using = instead of LIKE. It still returns no result.

Comment: I do not see how that is possible unless *none* of the columns contain the exact phrase you entered. Obviously something is different on your end than what we are expecting. But it is impossible to say what, as there are too many variable .. To keep this thread from turning into a book, create a small *self-contained* example (with data). Then others we can test it and pinpoint what is wrong. It does not need to include all of the tables. Two should be enough to demonstrate the problem. (I know you tried to post all the relevant info, but we have gone as far as we can go without a data sample)

Comment: *I do not see how that is possible unless* .. or you changed the `where` clause to use `AND` instead of `OR`. But again, that is just guessing...

Comment: I've made a git for people to download and test the files and data. I don't have coldfusion hosting to demo the application. So if anyone wants to copy the repo and get the files as they are now they can. The link is in the question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you're looking for:

```
<cfquery name="search_all">
SELECT DISTINCT
    people.first_name,
    people.last_name,
    state_lkp.state,
    zip_lkp.zip,
    number_lkp.phone_number,
    email_lkp.email,
    country_lkp.country,
    address_lkp.address,
    city_lkp.city,
    count(distinct email_lkp.email_id) as mail_count,
    count(distinct number_lkp.phone_number_id) as number_count,
    people.people_id
FROM
    people 
    LEFT JOIN state_lkp ON state_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
    LEFT JOIN zip_lkp ON zip_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
    LEFT JOIN number_lkp ON number_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
    LEFT JOIN email_lkp ON email_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
    LEFT JOIN country_lkp ON country_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
    LEFT JOIN city_lkp ON city_lkp.people_id = people.people_id 
    LEFT JOIN address_lkp ON address_lkp.people_id = people.people_id
WHERE
    people.last_name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim( lCase(form.search_bar) )#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500"> OR
    people.first_name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim( lCase(form.search_bar) )#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500"> OR
    people.first_name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim( lCase(form.search_bar) )#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500"> OR
    address_lkp.address LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#trim( lCase(form.search_bar) )#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">
    -- more filters here
GROUP BY
    people.people_id DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Also consider adding aliases to your table names. It's a bit easier to read to code.

Comment: That's actually what I had before, here's the problem with that. It doesn't return values as it should in theory. Say for example I have 10 entries, 8 of them have the country value 'USA' and 2 have the value of 'Japan'. If I use the old code I had, which is similar to both yours and the other gentleman's, it would return all 10 entries, despite the fact that 2 of them have 'Japan' instead of 'USA.' I should have made that clarification before. I'll edit my original post to point that out.

Comment: And yeah, aliases would be better. But this is a demo I'm cooking up for an interview so I'm not to worry about that. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's a little weird. Can you and have you tried using inner joins instead of left joins? I betting the issue is how you join, but not positive.

Comment: Ok, I've tried left, inner, left outer, outer and right joins. All of them return the same result. It's probably because the % character matches any and all characters. I need something more selective. Hell I might just go with my first hunch and make the user select what they want to search by.

Comment: Dump out your form.search_bar variable right before the query. Make sure it's actually being populated instead of using an empty string which would produce those kind of results.

Comment: Also - turn on request level debugging so you can see what query you're actually running after it's built. Then put it in a SQL Editor and tweak it as needed.

Comment: I have a cfdump for the entire form set up and cfabout tag to stop just before the query itself. From what it shows form.search_bar does contain values, the values I want passed along so that's not the problem. I'll try turning on request level debugging and seeing that I can do with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an SQL reference such as people.last_name in a CFIF statement, as per below:

```
<cfif LCase(people.last_name) eq LCase(form.search_bar)>
    people.last_name LIKE LTrim(RTrim(<cfqueryparam value="%#form.search_bar#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">))
```

If you are trying to create a single search that searches multiple fields, just string together a series of OR statements together:

```
WHERE
    people.first_name like <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(form.search_bar)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">
    OR people.last_name like <cfqueryparam value="%#trim(form.search_bar)#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="500">
etc. etc.
```